# How do I get the blog teaser view display on a content type?

Tags: nodes

I know. I write English language really bad, horrible. I apologize.

I created a blog (with the core's [blog module](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/blog). Also I have a content type called **my-content-type** :). I need the blog teaser view is displayed in my my-content-type.

I installed *Display Suite*. So, my-content-type has the *Display settings* option. With this option I can choose the desired view, in my case the teaser view. OK, very good! Now, but how do I get the blog teaser view is displayed in my-content-type?

Can I do this without *Views*?

Greetings!

Comment: Views is primarily for making **lists** of nodes.  What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Please do not cross post http://stackoverflow.com/q/32752510/1312737

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **Short answer:**

Yes, you could do it without views. But, it wouldn't be ideal.

### **Long answer:**

Display suite module will let you control the display of the particular content type and its fields. It won't allow you to control the display of a different content type from the other.
E.g. For your **my-content-type**, it will allow you to change the display settings of the fields of this content type.

If you wish to display teasers of nodes of the **blog** content type, on the node pages of **my-content-type**, you will have to do the follow the steps below:

**Without views:**

1. Create a custom module.
2. Load the **blog** `$node` using `node_load` on **my-content-type** node page.
3. Using `node_view` on the `$node` get the node in the teaser view of the node.
4. Use `drupal_render` to render the loaded teasers in a custom block created using `hook_block_info`.
5. Place this block in an region only on the **my-content-type** node page.

**With views:**

1. Create a view block of content of type **blog**.
2. Select the display method to be **content**, and select **teaser** from the settings.
3. Apply additional settings (filters, relations) as required.
4. Place this block on the node page of **my-content-type**.

In other words you let views build your query for you. And you also get an additional advantage of using other features provided by the views module like caching, etc.

Comment: Yes! With Views everything is easy. However, I think it's strange that Drupal has no way to process the teaser views. Drupal forces me to install a contributed module to achieve teaser views.